# How to make a java client code to send data to a Netty4 socket with String encoders and decoders?

Tags: java, apache-camel, client, netty-socketio

**Situation:**

I've a *netty4* socket running on

```
netty4:tcp://localhost:5020?sync=true&amp;encoder=#stringEncoder&amp;decoder=#stringDecoder
```

.. and want to send data to this socket, using some client code.

**Question:**

How can I do that? I guess that a plain created socket will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this example. It includes everything youre looking for including decoding and encoding -> [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=zhu410289616/RHSocketServerDemo-Netty/RHSocketServerDemo-Netty-master/RHSocketServerDemo/src/com/zrh/netty4/tcp/TcpServer.java#)

Comment: In my case i only need the client code because i have socket up and running and if i using you client code it is getting connected to my socket but its running decoder tow times and encoder is not getting executed...

Comment: @SachinSingh Just go to the client code there then! did you see that ?

Comment: yes I have gone through the client code in pipeline you are adding FrameDecoder , FrameEncoder , Decoder and Encoder . I just need String Decoder and String Encoder so i removed frame Encoder and decoder but when i running it my decoder is running twice and encoder is not getting executed..

Comment: Let me explain wat I m trying to achive  I have an apache camel route <route id="sampleSocketService">
         <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5020?sync=true&amp;encoder=#stringEncoder&amp;decoder=#stringDecoder"/>
         <to uri="log:sampleSocketService?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true"/>
     </route>                                                                                                        I want to send data to this socket using some java client code